# japanese, korean characters not showing up in lists, but show up fine when printed separately

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have strings of characters in different languages, mainly Japanese, and they show up fine when I try to print them as strings. However, when I add many of them to a python list, and then print out the list, they display as text like this: xe9

for example:

```
string1 = "西野カナ- NO. 1"
string2 = "첫눈처럼 너에게 가겠다"

list1 = []

list1.append(string1)
list1.append(string2)

print list1

for item in list1:
    print item
```

These two prints will give me different outputs:

```
['\xe8\xa5\xbf\xe9\x87\x8e\xe3\x82\xab\xe3\x83\x8a- NO. 1 NEW', '\xec\xb2\xab\xeb\x88\x88\xec\xb2\x98\xeb\x9f\xbc \xeb\x84\x88\xec\x97\x90\xea\xb2\x8c \xea\xb0\x80\xea\xb2\xa0\xeb\x8b\xa4']

  西野カナ- NO. 1 NEW
  첫눈처럼 너에게 가겠다
```

How would I get the list to print the actual characters too?

Comment: Can you upgrade to python 3?  Working with unicode in Python 2 is a road to frustration.

Comment: A list's `str` contains the `repr` of its items. Try `print repr(string1)` to see where the escapes come from.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,when you print a list or write to a file, it internally calls the `str()` method,and list internally calls `repr()` on its elements. So you are seeing is `repr()` returns.

```
print repr(string1)
'\xe8\xa5\xbf\xe9\x87\x8e\xe3\x82\xab\xe3\x83\x8a- NO. 1'
```

It is really discouraged.So if you want to avoid encoding problem, you should start to think seriously about switching to Python3.

You can check out [this](http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/) or see [unicode in python2 and python3](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/5/unicode-in-2-and-3/)